# For any complex $z$, $|z-1|\leq |z-j|+|z-j^2|$

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, euclidean-geometry, geometric-inequalities

> Let $z\in \mathbb C$. Prove that  $|z-1|\leq |z-j|+|z-j^2|$

This inequality appears as an exercise in a book for highschoolers. It is marked as very difficult.
$j=\exp(2i\pi/3)$  denotes a third root of unity.

I tried squaring both sides, and making use of $j^2=-1-j$, as well as $\bar j=j^2$ but I haven't made significant progress...

---

Remark: In retrospect it seems obvious that the problem cannot be solved without geometric insights, that I didn't know of at the time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

(The following is equivalent to Aqua's elegant answer. I'm just stating it to demonstrate a self-contained solution.)

Start with the identity
$$
 (z-1)(j-j^2) = (z-j)(1-j^2) + (z-j^2)(j-1) \, .
$$
Then apply the triangle inequality and use that
$$
|j-j^2| = |1-j^2| = |j-1| \, .
$$

Comment: Notice that triangle inequality is equivalent to Ptolemy's inequality (proof goes via inversion)

Comment: @Aqua: Yes, that's why I explicitly stated  that this is equivalent to your answer!

Answer (score 11):

Let $A\sim 1$, $B\sim j$ and $C\sim j^2$ then $ABC$ is an equilateral triangle in $\mathbb{C}$. Let $D\sim z$. Then by [Ptolemy's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy%27s_inequality) we have:

$$AD\cdot BC\leq AB\cdot CD+AC\cdot BD$$

Since $BC=AB = AC$ and $AD =|z-1|$, $CD=|z-j^2|$, $BD =|z-j|$ we get what we want.